# Node JS unit test - cloud function, how to call to inner function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I'm using AVA framework (https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/HEAD/docs/01-writing-tests.md) 
to test Cloud Function on GCP written in NodeJS. 
i'm trying to unit test an inner function inside my cloud function.

My testing  code looks as follow:

```
const test = require(`ava`);
const uuid = require(`uuid`);
const sinon = require(`sinon`);


const triggerResultsService = require(`..`).triggerResultsService;
const consoleLog = sinon.stub(console, 'log');
const sendToTransferService = require(`..`).triggerResultsService.sendToTransferService;

test('resolves with unicorn', t => {

    const filename = uuid.v4();
     sendToTransferService(filename, () =>{


     });

     return Promise().then(result => {
         t.is(result, 'unicorn');
     });
});
```

My Cloud function code looks as the following:

```js
/**
 * Generic background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
 *
 * @param {object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {function} callback The callback function.
 */

var request = require("request");

exports.triggerResultsService = (event, callback) => {
  var file = event.data;
  var fileName = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf('/')).toLowerCase().trim();
  if(!fileName.includes('temp-') && fileName.includes('.csv.gz')) {
    console.log("file name is in correct location, sending options");
    sendToTransferService(file);
    sendStatusEmail("Transfer File Call successful");
  };
  callback();
};

function sendToTransferService(file) {
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: process.env.TRANSFER_SERVICE_URL,
    body: {
       fileName: file.name,
       bucketName: file.bucket
    },
    json: true
   };
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(options, function (err, resp) {
       if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return reject({err: err});
       }
    return resolve({responsebody:resp.body});
    });
  });
}

   function sendStatusEmail(statusMessage) {
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: process.env.EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_URL,
    body: {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        to: [process.env.SLACK_EMAIL],
        cc: [''],
        bcc: [''],
        subject: process.env.EMAIL_SUBJECT,
        body: statusMessage
    },
    json: true
  };

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(options, function (err, resp) {
       if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return reject({err: err});
       }
    return resolve({responsebody:resp.body});
    });
 });
}
```

I'm not able to reach the function sendToTransferService .
Any ideas what should I require/declare

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your easiest path is to turn that function into its own module, and export it from there.  It will be accessible to any other code that imports the module, including your Cloud Functions code.

Comment: Thanks, even though I prefer not to change functionality for testing I think I will go with this approach.